# Dynamic div loaded only after second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've got an element in the DOM that's draggable and when it's clicked, I want to grab the x/y coordinates (not shown in this example, but for the future) and the height of tooltip that fades in.  The source text for the tooltip is an AJAX call and can be of variable length.  My problem currently is that the `shown.bs.tooltip` event is only fired on the `second` click on the triggering element. 
code:

```
        $('#click').draggable();
        $(document.body).on('click', function () {

            tooltipManager.title();
        });
        $('#click').on('shown.bs.tooltip', function () {
            console.log('from getHeight: ' + getHeight($('.tooltip')));
        });
        var tooltipManager = {
            title: function () {
                //ajax code to get title from database
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    url: "Service.asmx/GetDrugs",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        //bootstrap uses the title attribute to set the html inside the tooltip
                        //here it's set to the results of the AJAX
                        var $tooltipData = prettyTooltip(data.d);
                        var offset = $('#click').offset();
                        var windowSize = [
                            width = $(window).width(),
                            height = $(window).height()
                        ]
                        //this fires on the first click
                        console.log(window.width);
                        console.log(offset.top);
                        $('#click').tooltip({
                            trigger: 'click',
                            html: true,
                            placement: tooltipManager.placement.setPlacement(data.d),
                            title: $tooltipData.html()
                            //it seems to me that it would be better design to call the tooltipManager
                            //setPlacement function, but since it's an async request, it fails
                        });
                        //if I add click() at the above line I get an infinite loop of AJAX calls

                    },
                    error: function (xhr) {
                        console.log('failed: ' + xhr.status);
                    }
                });
            },
            placement: {
                left: 'left',
                top: 'top',
                right: 'right',
                bottom: 'bottom',
                //if the value of getHeight is over a certain amount
                //I want to change the position of the tooltip
                setPlacement: function () {
                    var height = getHeight($('.tooltip'));
                    var place = '';
                    if (height < 150) {
                        place = 'right';
                    }
                    else {
                        place = 'left'
                    }
                    return place;
                }
            }
        }
        //not sure if this is good design to have this not a property of the tooltipManager object
        //this works currently for placing the tooltip in the correct position
        function prettyTooltip(data) {
            var $div = $('<div>');
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var $p = $('<p>').text(data[i]).appendTo($div);
            }
            return $div;
        }
        function getHeight(el) {
            return $(el).height();
        }
```

If I use the `one` method instead of `on` and I add a click() where the code indicates, the tooltip fires on the first click, but I can't get the offset after the one-time click.  How can I make sure I retain all my current functionality and not require two clicks to show the tooltip?

EDITED: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RxtBq/)

Comment: Anyone care to comment on why this was worthy of a down arrow?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but most likely because it's off topic on Programmers.SE. Why didn't you post it on Stack Overflow where it belongs?

Comment: Because I wanted to get a perspective from a different group of users, and I never would have imagined that it was off topic considering many of the questions I read before posting.

Comment: Rough rule of thumb: If you would solve the problem by writing code it's SO, if you would discuss it with other people at the whiteboard it's Programmers (more the architectural view). Lines can be blurred sometimes but this one seems rather clear a SO topic.

Comment: @thorstenmüller fair enough, makes sense.

Comment: can you put this in a jsfiddle? (or is it too much?)

Comment: @gloomy.penguin I've never used jsFiddle with AJAX requests (although I know you can).  I'll work something up with some code that doesn't fetch from a database.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the event `shown.bs.tooltip`.  Is that a Bootstrap thing?  If so, we should probably add a Bootstrap tag to this.

Comment: Yes, it is.  Added a bootstrap tag.

Comment: maybe something with html/css positioning. since the first event is captured on all ```document.body``` while the second only on ```#click```. 2 questions come to mind: 1. is this intentional or by mistake? 2. can you show us some html/css (or better - a jsFiddle/jsbin as working example)

Comment: If you replace the AJAX with a simple string, will it work?  It sort of looks like the asynchronous nature of your AJAX call is causing the first click to start and complete without loading the tooltip string.  Perhaps you should preload it, or make the AJAX call synchronous.

Comment: Added a fiddle to show the behavior.

Comment: Seems like a timing issue. Don't take my advise as it's a bad one, but I sometimes solve a timing issue with a setTimeout and go home on time to my wife and kids. The Gods of the web are furious, but I will worry about them later.

Comment: @EranMedan I don't like that's a good idea.  I don't want to go home to your wife and kids :)

Comment: @wootscootinboogie, do you need to fetch the tooltip's content fresh every time, or only once?

Comment: @makla I need to get it fresh every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Youre `document.body` needs to be clicked once to initiate the tooltip. So at the bottom of your document.ready just add a click event. Before the first click was initiating the tooltip and then the second click on the actual `#click` was showing it.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/RxtBq/2/

I just added

```
$(document.body).click();
```

right before the end of `$(document).ready(function () {`

**EDIT:**

Alternatively. You can get rid of the:

```
$(document.body).on('click', function () {
            tooltipManager.title();
        });
```

And just call the `tooltipManager.title();` at the end of the document.ready function.

http://jsfiddle.net/RxtBq/3/

The most important part is that `tooltipManager.title();` is called before you try and click the `#click` div

Comment: Yes I tried to explain it. Wait a sec im about to edit for easier solution

Comment: @gloomy.penguin See my edit. It should make sense. You jsut have to call `tooltipManager.title();` so the tooltip is created for when you try and click the div

Comment: @Kierchon when the data source is coming from an AJAX request this still doesn't load the data on the first click.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie It should load the data on the $(document).ready() function. Thats where the `tooltipManager.title();` is called and in that function is what calls the ajax so you shouldnt even need a click

Comment: @wootscootinboogie Whats happening when you try this code? Does it just take two clicks? I think it might be AJAX takign too long and you just have to wait. Try loading the page and waiting like 20-30 secodnds then making a click. Let me know what happens please

Comment: @Kierchon hah, I dont' know what I was doing a second ago, but I just added that click event and it works (although I swear it didn't a second ago :)).  I knew the gist of the problem, but I didn't quite grok that the click needed to be before calling the title() function to fill the content.  +1 for cleverly adding the click event on the document ready.  I'm going to steal this one :)

Comment: @wootscootinboogie Do I get that beautiful bounty?? I think you have to award it as well as accepting

Comment: @Kierchon you will :), it says I have to wait 23 hours before I can award it.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie ahh okay. Wasnt positive on how they worked. Thanks

Comment: @Kierchon Yeah, they do that so people have the opportunity to accept a potentially better answer that may come afterward.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is all of the tooltip events are colliding in some way. If you need to fetch the tooltip content fresh every time, one way is to destroy and reinitialize.

Note that the following code also listens for the additional click to hide the tooltip. (If that's not what you wanted, let me know).

```
if ($('.tooltip:visible').length) { // destroy
  $('#click')
    .tooltip('destroy');
} else { // reinitialize
  $('#click')
    .tooltip('destroy')
    .tooltip({
      trigger: 'click',
      html: true,
      title: $tooltipData.html()})
    .tooltip('show');
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RxtBq/4/.

Comment: I dont know if this will work. He mentioned that he wanted to pull the XY coordinates from the div. Look in the console on his/my fiddles. They will log the coordinates but yours does not. I think it gets lost when you destroy it

Answer (score 0):

you can place a `.tooltip('show')` after the tooltip is created

```
$('#click').tooltip({
                    trigger: 'click',
                    html: true,
                    title: $tooltipData.html()

                }).tooltip('show');
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/g5mbn/

Comment: what is the browser you have tested with i can see it showing tooltip in single click in chrome

Comment: I am using chrome too. Click it once to open. Then click again to close and again to open and it starts blinking